# How to display list grid or flex using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-grid

How to display grid or flex using CSS like example below:

```html
<ul class="product columns-4">
  <li class="product type-product">Product 1</li>
  <li class="product type-product">Product 2</li>
  <li class="product type-product">Product 3</li>
  <li class="product type-product">Product 4</li>
  <li class="product type-product">Product 5</li>
  <li class="product type-product">Product 6</li>
  <li class="product type-product">Product 7</li>
  <li class="product type-product">Product 8</li>
  <li class="product type-product">Product 9</li>
  <li class="product type-product">Product 10</li>
  <li class="product type-product">Product 11</li>
  <li class="product type-product">Product 12</li>
  <li class="product type-product">Product 13</li>
  <li class="product type-product">Product 14</li>
</ul>
```

the continue product list will be repeat the same layout

[Example Picture Display Grid Flex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeYN1.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To implement this, you can use CSS **grid**. For more details, see comments in code.

```css
.product.columns-4 {
  display: grid; /* make grid container */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr); /* create template with 5 columns per row */
  column-gap: 1rem; /* add gaps between cells (column) */
  row-gap: 1rem; /* add gaps between cells (rows) */
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

/* show cells' area */
.product.type-product {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  border: 0.2rem solid tomato;
  min-height: 100px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1; /* make cell square */
}

/* encrease cells we want (#1, #11) */
.product.type-product:nth-child(10n + 1) {
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
  grid-row: auto / span 2;
}
```

```html
<ul class="product columns-4">
  <li class="product type-product">Product 1</li>
  <li class="product type-product">Product 2</li>
  <li class="product type-product">Product 3</li>
  <li class="product type-product">Product 4</li>
  <li class="product type-product">Product 5</li>
  <li class="product type-product">Product 6</li>
  <li class="product type-product">Product 7</li>
  <li class="product type-product">Product 8</li>
  <li class="product type-product">Product 9</li>
  <li class="product type-product">Product 10</li>
  <li class="product type-product">Product 11</li>
  <li class="product type-product">Product 12</li>
  <li class="product type-product">Product 13</li>
  <li class="product type-product">Product 14</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: its work! thanks a lot, you save my day

Answer (score 0):

You can use display grid, and grid-template-areas to make 5 column and 4 row, like this:

```
.container{
    grid-template-areas:
    "1 1 2 3 4"
    "1 1 5 6 7"
    "8 9 10 11 11"
    "12 13 14 11 11"
}
```

Don't forget to write grid-area on every class/element/id